# why this link works even after logout(or invalidate session)?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have generated dynamic delete link for each row in a table in jsp. When I click on that link It should delete the associated row,It works Fine. But it should not delete the row once I logged out..I copied the delete link and logged out..Now If I run that link It redirects me to Login page, If I login again viewed the students in a table..It deletes that particular row.

Why this even after removed the attribute and invalidate the session It still able to reach the servlet?

generated link for delete student..

```
http://localhost:8080/feeManagement/Delete_Action_Student?delete=67657
```

Here are my DeleteStudent,Logout servlets.

```
@WebServlet("/Delete_Action_Student")
public class Delete_Action_Student extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Delete_Action_Student() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getAttribute("Accemail") != "") {
            String id = request.getParameter("delete");
            try {
                if (StudentDAOimpl.removeStudent(id)) {
                    request.setAttribute("msg", "deleted successfully");
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Delete_Student").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("msg", "failed to remove");
                    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Delete_Student").forward(request, response);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/loginjsp.jsp");
        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

Logout snippet.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
     session.removeAttribute("Accemail");
     session.invalidate();
     response.sendRedirect("loginjsp.jsp");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the behavior of browser to store the url where you came from to login page. So After successful login it redirect to that url.

After successful login if you want to land always to home page you can do that by using filter.